# For AAAI template, what is the proper way to format authors when there are too many authors?

Tags: author

In [AAAI template](https://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit18.zip), what is the proper way to format authors when there are too many authors from the same affiliation? The example given in the section "Formatting Author Information — Alternative Method" even has syntax errors.

```
\author{AuthorOne},\textsuperscript{1}
\author{AuthorTwo},\textsuperscript{2}
\author{AuthorThree},\textsuperscript{3}
\author{AuthorFour},\textsuperscript{4}
\author{AuthorFive}, \textsuperscript{5}\\
\textsuperscript{1}AffiliationOne}\\
\textsuperscript{2}AffiliationTwo}\\
\textsuperscript{3}AffiliationThree}\\
\textsuperscript{4}AffiliationFour}\\
\textsuperscript{5}AffiliationFive}\\
\{email, email\}@affiliation.com,
email@affiliation.com,
email@affiliation.com,
email@affiliation.com
```

Using `\and` to separate authors seems to appear strange, as there are small "and"s between every two neighboring authors.

Comment: You post a snippet, you are talking aboput AAAI. You know about AAAI, i don't. Where can we find the template? What syntax errors? Have you asked the editors what to do? They will process your content, it might not even be worth worrying about this right now. They might use a completely different software.

Comment: @Johannes_B I added a link. Sorry about that.

Comment: line 100 of the tex file from the template makes me laugh. Journal templates, always funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe they (or you) want something like that

[image: xuhdev]

```
\def\year{2018}\relax
%File: formatting-instruction.tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} %DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{aaai18}  %Required
\usepackage{times}  %Required
\usepackage{helvet}  %Required
\usepackage{courier}  %Required
\usepackage{url}  %Required
\usepackage{graphicx}  %Required
\frenchspacing  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  %Required
%PDF Info Is Required:
  \pdfinfo{
/Title (2018 Formatting Instructions for Authors Using LaTeX)
/Author (AAAI Press Staff)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
 \begin{document}
 \author{Walther Wombat,\textsuperscript{1}
Alfonso Alpaca,\textsuperscript{2}
Carl Capybara,\textsuperscript{3}\\
\textsuperscript{1}{Wallaby}\\
\textsuperscript{2}{Alexandria}\\
\textsuperscript{3}{Canberra}\\
email@wolfsburg.com,
email@alexandria.com, 
email@canberra.com}
\title{The Water Mill}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Or like that

[image: xuhdev2]

```
\def\year{2018}\relax
%File: formatting-instruction.tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} %DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{aaai18}  %Required
\usepackage{mwepage}  %Required
\usepackage{times}  %Required
\usepackage{helvet}  %Required
\usepackage{courier}  %Required
\usepackage{url}  %Required
\usepackage{graphicx}  %Required
\frenchspacing  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  %Required
%PDF Info Is Required:
  \pdfinfo{
/Title (2018 Formatting Instructions for Authors Using LaTeX)
/Author (AAAI Press Staff)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
 \begin{document}
 \author{Walther Wombat,\\
{Wolfsburg}\\
email@wolfsburg.com,
\And
Alfonso Alpaca,\\
{Alexandria}\\
email@alexandria.com, 
\And
Carl Capybara,\\
{Canberra}\\
email@canberra.com}
\title{The Water Mill}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

a small tweak based on Johannes_B's answer to making sure the font for affiliation and email is correct:

```
\author{au1,\textsuperscript{1}
au2,\textsuperscript{2}\\}

\affiliations{
\textsuperscript{1}{University of au1}\\
\textsuperscript{2}{University of au2}\\
email of au1,
email of au2}
```

or

```
\author {
    % Authors
    First Author Name,\textsuperscript{\rm 1}
    Second Author Name, \textsuperscript{\rm 2}
    Third Author Name \textsuperscript{\rm 1}
}
\affiliations {
    % Affiliations
    \textsuperscript{\rm 1} Affiliation 1\\
    \textsuperscript{\rm 2} Affiliation 2\\
    firstAuthor@affiliation1.com, secondAuthor@affilation2.com, thirdAuthor@affiliation1.com
}
```